# Testing a value in a pythonic way

Tags: python-3.x

I want to do

```
if ((a,b,c==1,1,1)):
    <do something if a,b,c are all 1>
```

The above, does not work. Is there something similar that will?

Here are some examples that do not agree with the comments below. 
This looks sensible

```
if((1,1,0)==(1,1,0)): print("same")
same
```

As does this

```
if((1,1,0)!=(1,1,1)): print("different")
different



In [86]: if(1,1,0==1,1,0): print("same")
same

In [87]: if(1,1,0==1,1,1): print("same")
same

In [88]: if(1,0,0==1,1,1): print("same")
same
```

So my original Q is actually an issue associated with parentheses-brackets . The if will pass TRUE  because without the comparison being between lists or tuples I was only comparing the centre elements either side of the == or !=

Comment: Use `all` here: `if all(x == 1 for x in (a, b, c)):`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm not sure that `all` will work for OP. If it would then OPs code should work as well.

Comment: if those are binary 1s (i.e. if you wanna check if none of them is 0, you could even use all((a,b,c))

Comment: @DeepSpace Fair point, their code should work as well. I think this should be closed as lacking a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks. I just got if ([a,b,c]==[1,1,1]): to work

Comment: They are not binary

Comment: @nerak99 Doesn't make sense. If `[a,b,c]==[1,1,1]` works then `(a,b,c)==(1,1,1)` should work as well. You have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes to post some CLI records of both cases.

Comment: OK, this code is part off an exercise .

Comment: This line works\n { if ([board[row][0],board[row][1],board[row][2]]==[(player),(player),(player)]):} \nWhereas this one fails \n {if (board[row][0],board[row][1],board[row][2]==(player),(player),(player)):}

Comment: The only difference is the square brackets

Comment: TBH I think it is something to do with me dealing with array elements rather than just integers. Even though the array elements are just integers.

Comment: So I have edited the Q to clarify, show repeatability, and illuminate. Of course if you can't answer a question feel free to critique it or vote it down or whatever makes you feel good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work

```
 if [a,b,c]==[1,1,1]:
```

also  this is fine

```
if (a,b,c)==(1,1,1):
```

This code is short, repeatable and is verifiable. Just in case anyone wondered.

The fundamental error I was seeing here was that I was effectively doing

```
if (1,1,1==1,0,1): ...
```

Rather than

```
if (1,1,1)==(1,0,1): ...
```

Because

```
if (1,1,0 == 0,0,0): print ("same")
... 
same
```

i.e.

```
>>> 1,1,0==0,0,0
```

(1, 1, True, 0, 0)

Whereas

```
    >>> (1,1,0)==(0,0,0)
False
```

In other words, I was only testing the last element of the LHS with the first of the RHS of the ==.

Comment: I have clarified the OP. It appears that the test needs to be between two lists or tuples but not just comma separated values. I genuinely think this was a reasonable Q.